# Change behavior of tab key in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, key-bindings

I have been using Sublime Text 2 for a little over a few weeks now, and just a little while ago, my key bindings changed and I couldn't get them back like I wanted, so I uninstalled/reinstalled Sublime Text so everything would be clean, I also deleted my AppData folder. I use the Emmet package a LOT so I also reinstalled it and it works fine using the tab key to complete the desired action in an HTML file, but for some reason when I'm in a CSS file, I hit tab and get undesirable results. for example, I type the following:

```
    .header
```

and I hit tab to indent and it changes to

```
    :;
```

What do I need to change to keep this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be a bug with Emmet. I disabled Emmet and it went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an issue submitted to [emmet-sublime](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime): https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/220.

Add this do your *User/Emmet.sublime-settings* file to completely disable the feature:

```
{
  "disable_tab_abbreviations_for_scopes": "source.css"
}
```

Apparently, they are working on fixing the feature.